# Convert SQL To Doctrine Query Builder Code in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have this sql query

```
DELETE FROM attachments
     WHERE  ( attachment_id IN (
        SELECT s.attachment_id FROM (
             SELECT a0_.attachment_id
             FROM attachments a0_
            WHERE a0_.attachment_entity = 'user' AND a0_.attachment_foreign_key = ?
             ) AS s 
   ))
```

[doctrine native query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ8n9.png)

and i want to convert to Doctrine 2 Code,

i use some thing like this:

```
$query->delete($this->entityClass, 'Attachments')
            ->where($query->expr()->in('Attachments.attachmentId',
                $subQuery->select('AttachmentEntity.attachmentId')
                    ->from($this->entityClass, 'AttachmentEntity')
                    ->where("AttachmentEntity.attachmentEntity =:model")
                    ->andWhere("AttachmentEntity.attachmentForeignKey =:userId")
                    ->getDQL()
            ))
            ->setParameters(
                [
                    'model'  => 'user',
                    'userId' => $userId,
                ]
            )
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

but i got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrdDb.png)

any help plz.

Comment: i use php 7 and Doctrine 2 ORM

Comment: i found in mysql i can't delete records that select from same table

Comment: one solution is i use native query in doctrine but i don't want, i wana use doctrine query builder